# How to multiply all values in two lists and attain a corresponding matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

So I'm fairly new to python and was wondering how I could possibly multiply every element in one list with every element in another and construct a matrix with these new elements.
For example:

If I have two lists:

```
alpha_p_arra = [0.01,0.02,0.03....,0.1], 
alpha_b_arra = [0.01,0.02,0.03....,0.2]
```

Similar to the format in the picture, could I create a matrix with the shape of two lists (being 20x10) that has the corresponding multiplied values at those indexes? ie: at (0,0), it would be 0.01*0.01 or at (1,0), it would be 0.02*0.01.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Double list comprehension works: `[[i*j for i in alist] for j in blist]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can and should use `numpy` for this calculation:

```
import numpy as np

alpha_p_arra = np.arange(1, 11) / 100
alpha_b_arra = np.arange(1, 21) / 100

res = alpha_p_arra * alpha_b_arra[:, None]
```

Note that we change the shape of the second array so that `numpy` understands what is required via [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Output of `print(res)`:

```
[[0.0001 0.0002 0.0003 0.0004 0.0005 0.0006 0.0007 0.0008 0.0009 0.001 ]
 [0.0002 0.0004 0.0006 0.0008 0.001  0.0012 0.0014 0.0016 0.0018 0.002 ]
 [0.0003 0.0006 0.0009 0.0012 0.0015 0.0018 0.0021 0.0024 0.0027 0.003 ]
 [0.0004 0.0008 0.0012 0.0016 0.002  0.0024 0.0028 0.0032 0.0036 0.004 ]
 [0.0005 0.001  0.0015 0.002  0.0025 0.003  0.0035 0.004  0.0045 0.005 ]
 [0.0006 0.0012 0.0018 0.0024 0.003  0.0036 0.0042 0.0048 0.0054 0.006 ]
 [0.0007 0.0014 0.0021 0.0028 0.0035 0.0042 0.0049 0.0056 0.0063 0.007 ]
 [0.0008 0.0016 0.0024 0.0032 0.004  0.0048 0.0056 0.0064 0.0072 0.008 ]
 [0.0009 0.0018 0.0027 0.0036 0.0045 0.0054 0.0063 0.0072 0.0081 0.009 ]
 [0.001  0.002  0.003  0.004  0.005  0.006  0.007  0.008  0.009  0.01  ]
 [0.0011 0.0022 0.0033 0.0044 0.0055 0.0066 0.0077 0.0088 0.0099 0.011 ]
 [0.0012 0.0024 0.0036 0.0048 0.006  0.0072 0.0084 0.0096 0.0108 0.012 ]
 [0.0013 0.0026 0.0039 0.0052 0.0065 0.0078 0.0091 0.0104 0.0117 0.013 ]
 [0.0014 0.0028 0.0042 0.0056 0.007  0.0084 0.0098 0.0112 0.0126 0.014 ]
 [0.0015 0.003  0.0045 0.006  0.0075 0.009  0.0105 0.012  0.0135 0.015 ]
 [0.0016 0.0032 0.0048 0.0064 0.008  0.0096 0.0112 0.0128 0.0144 0.016 ]
 [0.0017 0.0034 0.0051 0.0068 0.0085 0.0102 0.0119 0.0136 0.0153 0.017 ]
 [0.0018 0.0036 0.0054 0.0072 0.009  0.0108 0.0126 0.0144 0.0162 0.018 ]
 [0.0019 0.0038 0.0057 0.0076 0.0095 0.0114 0.0133 0.0152 0.0171 0.019 ]
 [0.002  0.004  0.006  0.008  0.01   0.012  0.014  0.016  0.018  0.02  ]]
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding sample output to your great answer to help those of us who benefit from a bit of visualization.

Comment: oh thanks!!
Expanding on this further if possible though, how would I go about applying a function to each pair in the alpha_p_arra and alpha_b_arra instead of just multiplying.

For example,
at (0,0), subbing in both the alpha_p_arra element and the alpha_b_arra element at that index into a formula and so on for the pair at (0,1) and (0,2), etc. I'm think I have to apply some type of zero matrix

Comment: @DanielBoz, This is possible, but you should ask a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so that other users can find your Q&A :). You can message me (@jpp) to make sure I see it.

Comment: Also, if this answers your question as stated, you should consider accepting (green tick on left).